# How do I remove a space after a quotation mark in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to give some images their alts and titles in HTML but some of the text contains quotation marks. Doing the following results in a space after the quotation mark.

```
alt="&quot I am on fire and have dangerous cargo on board: keep well clear of me,&quot or &quot I am leaking dangerous cargo.&quot"
```

If I remove the space before the "I", then it won't recognise it as a quotation mark. I later replaced the "I" with "&#73" but that is tedious when I have a word after a mark. Does anyone know how to remove the space after the mark?

Comment: The quoted mark is with `;`, so you need to write good the string. It will be `&quot;`. If you write the `;` you can remove the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax for HTML entities is `&name;`. In this precise case, you should thus use `&quot;`, which would in turn give:

```
alt="&quot;I am on fire and have dangerous cargo on board: keep well clear of me,&quot;or &quot;I am leaking dangerous cargo.&quot;"
```